# Why do particular keys on my laptop malfunction intermittently?

Tags: laptop, keyboard

Google searching hasn't produced any hits that seem precisely analogous to my case. Symptoms:

- Problem only affects a small number of keys. They are not right next to one another but they are close (v, b, k and l are the worst).
- The problem only rarely occurs at startup. More usually it will occur after the machine has been on for a while.
- Sometimes pressing really hard on the key will cause the letter to be produced, but at other times it will do nothing.

The laptop is a Dell Adamo 13, running Windows Vista.

Comment: Mechanical failure..

Comment: Sounds like mechanical failure.  Particular keys will tend to be affected together, in a sort of zig-zag pattern across the keyboard, since the scan lines run that way, and usually a particular scan line is affected.  This kind of failure is especially likely if you ever spilled anything on the keyboard.

Answer (score 3):

If the keyboard has not been damaged (say by liquid spills) the most likely cause for many of the above reports is one of:

- the keyboard cable not making good contact with the connector
- a tiny break in one or more of the conductors in the cable
- a tiny break in one or more traces on the keyboard's circuit board

All of these can easily occur with age, be intermittent, respond to pressure or to changes in temperature, etc.

If reseating the connector for the keyboard cable doesn't fix it, your best bet is to replace the keyboard. They're cheap and this is an easy DIY job. Don't mess around putting pieces of paper in the machine, etc.

I've bought several replacement keyboards for Dell laptops (I've been using them since the C-series) on eBay with 100% success. Searching eBay for these words:

> Dell Adamo 13 keyboard

brings up many hits for new keyboards in the $10-$30 range, almost all from sellers with very high feedback ratings. And it's an easy swap. The Dell web site in the "support" pages has a service manual for your Vostro with R&R instructions for all field-swappable components, including the keyboard. Go for it :)

Disclaimer: No affiliation with Dell or eBay except as a satisfied customer of each.

Answer (score 2):

Could also be a malfunctioning Ctrl or Alt or Windows key sticking.  If the key gets stuck in the down position, some keys will no longer work since the key combo means something other than the plain letter.  If it happens, try pressing the Ctrl, Alt, Win keys (bounce the keys several times) to see if the keys are stuck and then the letter key by itself again.

Answer (score 1):

Hook up a regular USB keyboard.  Do the keys still function normally?  I would expect them to, it sounds like a hardware problem.  If they function correctly, then its most likely the keyboard itself.  I would find the manual for your laptop, it should be on the Dell website and find out how to remove the keyboard.  Once it is out, gently tap it, often crumbs and other debris can get under the keys and cause them to function poorly.  You might even get a can of compressed air and blow the in the keys to dislodge anything.  If its still not functioning, you can get a replacement from Dell.  Keyboards typically arent all that expensive.

Comment: Yes, the keys function normally with a USB keyboard plugged. Although I have had keyboards before where crumbs etc have got underneath the keys, I find that hard to square with the pattern of symptoms I've seen here where the keys sometimes work perfectly, sometimes require hard pressing, and sometimes don't respond at all.

Answer (score 1):

I had something similar with `B` and `N` keys on a Dell notebook that was fixed when I pressed the strip connector plug more firmly into its terminal. There was a distinct click at one end. My problems were worse when the pc had warmed up. However in my case problems included `B` and `N` as a response to just pressing `B`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work with a lot of machines. I was having similar problems. A good fix that makes sense is to go inside your computer, seems the motherboard main connector strip
creates a magnetic field and produces an effect where certain keys will not work.

So what the guy did on youtube that worked, and what I am trying that is working as I type this,
(<kbd>s</kbd> <kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>x</kbd> keys were not working), is to put a piece of paper to separate the keyboard from the
connector strip, he said he has not experienced problems since and I am hoping the same, so far so good.

you gotta try this for intermittent keys not working again, seems the heat and or magnetic field makes some keys unresponsive. A simple fix is to put paper between mb and connector ribbon. Go to first site for instruction with pictures. Its not youtube my mistake

More good reads on bottom site.....

https://defuse.ca/asuskeyboarddefect.htm

http://btoforums.com/showthread.php?t=2131

Comment: what youtube video? Please describe procedure in detail

Comment: Sorry but the explanation makes no sense. Any computer is FULL of very weak, rapidly-changing magnetic fields - any changing current in any conductor creates such - and if this was really an issue with anything we'd be seeing far more problems. Nor will a piece of paper do anything to block magnetic fields. What might be happening is the cable connector not making good contact with the cable (and this may change as things heat up). Adding a piece of paper may add a bit of pressure, increasing the contact...But you'd be much better off opening the connector and reseating the cable.

Comment: Also, adding pieces of paper to the machine may interfere with airflow. Don't do it.